# htaccess multiple urls to one page redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a bunch of url's like https://example.com/index.php?articles_id=XX, where XX is some number. I want to 
redirect all of them to https://example.com/maps.php (ignoring the parameters) but none of the redirect code I use works. When visiting the
original url, the browser just cycles until it finally times out. The second url is to a working page.

I first tried:

```
    RewriteRule ^articles_id=(.*)$ /maps.php [L,R=301]
```

then

```
    RewriteRule ^https://example.com/index.php?articles_id=(.*)$ /maps.php [L,R=301]
```

then

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php?articles_id=\ HTTP/ 
    RewriteRule ^index\.php?articles_id=$ https://example.com/maps.php [R=301,L]
```

and finally

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php?articles_id=\ HTTP/ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./maps.php [R=301,L]
```

There is other redirect code in the file that is working, like this one:

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Can someone please point out the reason why the redirects are not working?

Comment: Do you know this https://perishablepress.com/redirect-query-string-htaccess/

Comment: Try it out from the example step by step. Uncomment for a while your current work.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be code in the files that was preventing the redirect.